# What is the Save DC for Innate Spellcasting abilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

I'm creating an encounter with a Glabrezu, which has Innate Spellcasting of Power Word Stun. What is the Save DC? It says that the Glabrezu's spellcasting ability its Intelligence; does that mean 8, plus 4 from Intelligence? Does it add a Proficiency bonus? If so, what is that proficiency bonus?

Answer (score 8):

The spell save DC for a Glabrezu's innate spells is 16, it says so right near the start of the **Innate Spellcasting** trait block.

Comment: What! im using fantasy grounds and it doesnt appear nothing, only that its spellcasting ability its intelligence! thats weird.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't added? It's written in stat block in the monster manual.

Comment: You are right =) but thats weird, i got all the main books on FG and theres nothing, sorry for the silly question and thank you.

Comment: @LupaShiva, I'd suggest filing a bug ticket with FG.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by Erik, the *Glabrezu's* stat block does indeed list its *Innate Spellcasting* saving throw DC:

> Innate Spellcasting. The Glabrezu's spellcasting ability is Intelligence (spell save DC 16). The Glabrezu can innately cast the following spells [...]

---

This probably solves your problem.
However, this value isn't random - if it were not given, you could calculate it as follows.

Spell saving throw DCs are calculated as

> DC = 8 + proficiency bonus + spellcasting ability modifier

The proficiency boni of monsters are listed in the DMG, page 274. According to that table, the Glabrezu, being CR9, has a proficiency bonus of +4.
The table also lists save DCs, though I believe those are more intended for saving against the monster's abilities, not their spells. Either way, for balancing purposes, one should probably adhere to these values when setting ability scores (and, subsequently, spell save DCs) for a custom monster. For example, the glabrezu's *Innate Spellcasting* has the same DC as listed in the table.

Hence, with an INT modifier of +4, the Glabrezu's *Innate Spellcasting* save DC equals

> DC = 8 + 4 + 4 = 16

which is identical to the value given in the *MM*.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I wasn't aware of that. I changed it :)

Comment: SSD and KRyan brought that to my attention early in my time here, I like to share the collective wisdom.  Thanks, and I like your answer.

Comment: why did you delete your comment, though? It could have been helpful for future readers as well ^^

Comment: Because my brain did a boo boo.  Oops. *red face*

Comment: "I like to share the collective wisdom" - proceeds to delete collective wisdom. Jokes aside, you could rewrite the comment, it seems interesting, even if it would be out of order.